# Python Curses Border on Resize

Tags: python, curses

I am building a simple scrollable menu in Python 2.7 with curses and trying to make it scale for any window size, including if the terminal size changes (i.e. I want it to be larger or smaller while I'm using the menu). I have a simple test code that I'm using to try and figure out this problem. It seems, if this is possible, I am really close, but what I am seeing is that when I resize my terminal window (using mRemoteNG), the border draws lines to fill in space, as seen at the bottom of the screenshot, after I extended the window vertically:

[image: resize-test_border-lines]

The code I am using to test this is as follows:

```
import curses
import os

VERSION = "0.1-dev" #version number

screen = curses.initscr() #initialize the curses window

#Configure color pairs for showing select menu options as highlighted
curses.start_color() #enable color for highlighting menu options
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE) #color pair 1
highlightText = curses.color_pair(1) #color pair for highlighted menu option
normalText = curses.A_NORMAL #color pair for non-highlighted menu options

#Configure global variables for Curses
curses.noecho() #disable the keypress echo to prevent double input
curses.cbreak() #disable line buffers to run the keypress immediately
curses.curs_set(0)
screen.keypad(1) #enable keyboard use
screen.addstr(2, 2, "Screen Resize Test" + VERSION, curses.A_UNDERLINE)

#test screen resize
def main_screen():
    escape = False
    while escape == False:
        maxY, maxX = screen.getmaxyx()
        screen.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')
        screen.addstr(4, 2, "MaxY: " + str(maxY))
        screen.addstr(5, 2, "MaxX: " + str(maxX))
        screen.refresh()

        x = screen.getch()

        if x == ord("q"):
            escape = True




main_screen()


curses.endwin() # *** CRITICAL *** this closes the curses menu and returns user to bash
os.system('clear') #clears the screen to avoid curses remnants
```

I've tried many different placements of `screen.refresh()` and `screen.clear()`, but it never seems to get rid of the remnants of lines at the edges of the curses window. Obviously, if this is possible, I either can't figure out where to place one/both of these or I'm not on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program, you should check for curses.KEY_RESIZE as a return value from `getch`, and in that case, call `screen.erase`.

Also, the existing call to `screen.refresh` is unnecessary, since `screen.getch` does that anyway.

This works for me:

```
import curses
import os

VERSION = "0.1-dev" #version number

screen = curses.initscr() #initialize the curses window

#Configure color pairs for showing select menu options as highlighted
curses.start_color() #enable color for highlighting menu options
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE) #color pair 1
highlightText = curses.color_pair(1) #color pair for highlighted menu option
normalText = curses.A_NORMAL #color pair for non-highlighted menu options

#Configure global variables for Curses
curses.noecho() #disable the keypress echo to prevent double input
curses.cbreak() #disable line buffers to run the keypress immediately
curses.curs_set(0)
screen.keypad(1) #enable keyboard use
screen.addstr(2, 2, "Screen Resize Test" + VERSION, curses.A_UNDERLINE)

#test screen resize
def main_screen():
    escape = False
    while escape == False:
        maxY, maxX = screen.getmaxyx()
        screen.border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+')
        screen.addstr(4, 2, "MaxY: " + str(maxY))
        screen.addstr(5, 2, "MaxX: " + str(maxX))

        x = screen.getch()

        if x == ord("q"):
            escape = True
            curses.endwin()
        elif x == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
            screen.erase()
            screen.addstr(2, 2, "Screen Resize Test" + VERSION, curses.A_UNDERLINE)

main_screen()
```

Comment: if I add:

    `elif x == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
        screen.erase()`

on resize, the window goes blank until a keypress causes everything to be redrawn. I tried to add a `screen.refresh()` in the `elif` block, but that didn't seem to make a difference. Your suggestion does, however, fix the exact problem I was having with the ghost lines on resize.

Comment: I had forgotten a couple lines I added while continuing to work this issue on my own, which were causing the problem. I also didn't re-add the `screen.addstr()` line in the `elif` block, so once the screen was erased, a key press was the only thing to redraw everything.